# How can I evaluate this integral's value?

Tags: calculus

I have the integral $\int x(5x+8)^{15}$ and I cannot figure out how to evaluate it.

I think it's u substitution with $x$ but I can't figure out how.

Can someone please explain it to me in layman's language, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: You want $u=5x+8$

Comment: An alternative method, though rather inefficient is that you could expand the $(5x+8)^{15}$ via the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement).

Answer (score 3):

Setting $u=5x+8$:

Then $x = \frac{u-8}{5}$

And $dx = \frac{1}{5}du$

$$ \int x(5x+8)^{15}dx$$
$$ = \int\left(\frac{u-8}{5}\right)u^{15}\cdot\frac{1}{5}du$$
$$=\frac{1}{25}\int u^{16}-8u^{15}du$$

And evaluating this integral should not be a problem

Answer (score 1):

You can also integrate by parts:
$$\int x(5x+8)^{15}dx=\frac{x(5x+8)^{16}}{5\cdot16}-\int \frac{(5x+8)^{16}}{5\cdot16}dx=\frac{x(5x+8)^{16}}{80}-\frac{(5x+8)^{17}}{80\cdot17\cdot5}$$
$$=\frac{(5x+8)^{16}}{80}\left[x-\frac{5x+8}{85}\right]+C$$